# how can i make relation between INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and other table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin, information-schema

is it possible to make relation between INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and get TABLE_NAME and add it to other table

i want to make table has all the tables name and another table has all the field name

i need this table to make table have all tables name and another table has all fields name

Comment: Just asking, but you are aware that MySQL can query itself? See: [3.4 Getting Information About Databases and Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-information.html)

Comment: i know that but is it possible to make table and add foreign key from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: I suggest asking a higher level of what you want to achieve without trying to prescribe and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you ask isn't possible.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` isn't a normal sort of table that you can add constraints, triggers or other modification constants to. Its there to be *read only*.

Comment: i want to make table that has all name of all tables in my database

Comment: For what purpose do you want to would be a more worth while question.

Comment: i want to make table to store the actions in website like create or update or delete and i do not know how can i do that

Comment: 'actions in website' is a bit general however look at audit plugins and binary logs. Which is more appropriate depends on purpose. Add a new question with details.